# Mysterious missing content

Tags: lineno, missing, cuted

Given the following LaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}
\changefontsizes[11pt]{9pt}

\twocolumn[{\vskip 200pt}]

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{strip}
\hrule
\end{strip}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

There is a gap in the content between the second and third pages. It seems to be a bug triggered by the exact combination of elements in this document as I've been unable to remove any further elements and still reproduce the issue. But I'm rather lost to explain what's going on.

Comment: Both lineno and cuted patch quite heavily the output routine.

Comment: Dropping the `scrextend` package, removing the `\chagnefontsizes` and adding an `11pt` option to the package results in similar loss of text, now between pages 3 and 4.  The combination of `cuted` and `lineno` is probably the cause.

Comment: Looks like it's the `strip` environment. By deleting it, you get the whole text. Probably a bug in `cuted`, you could submit a bug report and use another solution for now, e.g. the multicol package.

Comment: @nox, how do I know whether its a bug is in lineno or cuted?

Comment: It's probably the combination of `lineno` and `cuted` as others pointed out. If you look into the `lineno` doc you will find a section "Known incompatibilities". I think that is the way. Maybe both packages use the same internals, so they are incompatible (at the moment). So I suggest you let both authors know and then the authors can look at the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `multicol` package instead of `cuted`, you can get what you are looking for, as mentioned in a comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}
\changefontsizes[11pt]{9pt}

\vspace*{200pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{multicols}

\hrule

\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```